# Why isn't this.value or $(this).val() responding in JavaScript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following `function`, which successfully increases the `value` of `input type="text"`

```
function deleteLine(arrayNumber) {
    $("#line" + arrayNumber + "_quantity").val(parseInt($("#line" + arrayNumber + "_quantity").val()) + 1);
}
```

I'm just wondering why these don't work instead, for a neater code:

```
$("#line" + arrayNumber + "_quantity").val(this + 1);
$("#line" + arrayNumber + "_quantity").val(this.value + 1);
$("#line" + arrayNumber + "_quantity").val($(this).val() + 1);
```

Comment: There's not enough information to answer this question well.

Comment: could you post the rest of the function?

Comment: Because `this` does not refer to the DOM element selected by `$("#line" + arrayNumber + "_quantity")`. It probably refers to `window` or `document` or whatever element the event handler is bound to if these lines are inside of one. Have a look at the MDN documentation to learn more about `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Comment: `this` is most likely `[window]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try like below,

```
$("#line" + arrayNumber + "_quantity").val(function (i, v) { return +v+1; });
```

Your version doesn't work because the `this` doesn't refer to the textbox.

Thanks [@FelixKing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388728/why-isnt-this-value-or-this-val-responding-in-javascript-jquery/14388759#comment20016152_14388759) for the unary operator.

Comment: Thanks. Slight change though: `return parseInt(v)+1`

Comment: @rybo111: You should pass a radix, `parseInt(v, 10)`, or just use unary plus: `return +v+1;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lineVar = $("#line" + arrayNumber + "_quantity");

 lineVar.val(parseInt(lineVar.val()) + 1);
```